# Session in Task Scheduling

Tags: session, laravel-5, cron, laravel-5.5

I need to get Session in Laravel Task Scheduling.
Below is my UserActivity Class

```
<?php
    namespace App\Console\Commands; 
    use Illuminate\Console\Command;

    class UserActivity extends Command
    {

        protected $signature = 'Example:test';

        protected $description = 'testing';


        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }


        public function handle()
        {
            $value = \Session::all();
            \Log::alert($value);
        }
    }
```

I got empty array in laravel.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You doesn't have access to session via laravel **task scheduling**

Answer (score 1):

There is no session, this is a console command. There is no Http request coming in with a cookie that could potentially be matched up to a session.